# Array VBScript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, charts

I have a classic ASP website,  we have taken the Flash components to generate charts to incorporate this functionality through a JavaScript library.

On the same page ASP, we read text files, the data is saved in arrays and these must be passed to the javascript function. This code is not a function, because depending on the selected menu, different files are read. It is a very extensive code.

```
 <%
···

ReDim LisOp (numop) 

ReDim Lisco (numop) 

ReDim LisVo (numop) 

aux = options
for i = 1 to numop
  p = InStr (aux, ",")
  if p> 0 Then
    LisOp (i - 1) = Left (aux, (p - 1))
    Right aux = (aux, (Len (aux) - p))
  else
    LisOp (i - 1) = aux
    aux = ""
  end if
Next
···
%>
```

In these variables LisOp, Lisco, LisVo we have data. The problem is when I want to pass this information to javascript:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV = "refresh" CONTENT = "<% = TieRefresco%>">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"> </ script>
  <script language="JavaScript">

  google.load ('visualization', '1 ', {' packages': ['table', 'corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback (draw);

  function draw () {
    var options = {title:'',
      legend: {position: "none"},
      hAxis: {textstyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial Black', size: 16}}
    };

    // Create data table object
    var google.visualization.DataTable datat = new (); / / DataTable Roles

    // Define columns
   datat.addColumn ('string', '<% = tOpciones%>'); / / Implicit domain column.
   datat.addColumn ('number', '<% = tVotos%>'); / / Implicit data column.
   datat.addColumn ({type: 'string' role: 'style'});
   datat.addColumn ({type: 'string' role: 'annotation'});

   for (var i = 0; i << numop%% => -1, i + +) {
     datat.addRow (['OP1', 450, 'color: green', '450 ']);
   }
   ···
 </ Script>
</ HEAD>
<BODY>
···
```

In the example I've left fixed values to the function addRow, but I need to pass the arrays created in Visual Basic script “LisOp, LisVo, LisCo”. With fixed values  runs perfect. Then I put code examples I've tried but have not worked to pass array values to function addRow:

I tried the VBArray (arrayObj) toArray () function; but it gives me an error and I did not make the graphic:

```
 var arrayObj;
 var jsArray;
 arrayObj = LisOp
 jsArray = VBArray (arrayObj) toArray ().;

 for (var i = 0; i << numop%% => -1, i + +) {
   datat.addRow ([jsArray[i], 450, 'color: green', '450 ']);
 }
```

I tried to make the loop for VBScript within the draw() function but does not work:

```
<% For i = 0 to numop%>
   datat.addRow ([<%=LisOp(i)%>, <%=LisVo(i)%>, <%=lisCo(i)%>, <%=LisVo(i)%>])
<% Next%>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've only had do this once before and I played with a bunch of different options trying to find something robust and reliable.

In the end, I had to break down and use a loop in VBA to deconstruct the object, calling a function in JavasScript to reconstruct it.

**Forgive this syntax, I haven't worked with VBA for along time -- it is sure to be wrong**

```
for i = 1 to numop
  jsSetLisOp (i, LisOp(i))
  jsSetLisCo (i, LisCo(i))
Next
```

**Javascript**

```
// Set up our magic function
var wrapper = (function() {
  var arr = [];

  function jsSetLisOp(idx, val)  {
    var o = arr[i] || {};
    o.LisOp = val;
  }

  function jsSetLisCo(idx, val)  {
    var o = arr[i] || {};
    o.LisCo = val;
  }

  return { 
    jsSetLisOp: jsSetLisOp,
    jsSetLisCo: jsSetLisCo
    arr = arr;
  };

}());


// Move this to a global level so we can share them with VBA
var jsSetLisOp = wrapper.jsSetLisOp;
var jsSetLisCo = wrapper.jsSetLisCo;

var jsobject = wrapper.arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, your problem is the js quoting of the generated data

```
<% For i = 0 to numop %>
   datat.addRow (['<%=LisOp(i)%>', <%=LisVo(i)%>, '<%=lisCo(i)%>', '<%=LisVo(i)%>']);
<% Next %>
```